# Integer GetterValue is not set in TextView

Tags: android, cursor, getter-setter

In my app I am using Getter and Setter in Bean Class. I have set a value into the setter and I tried to get the value by using getter.

Setter value is printed in Log.e But getter value is not set in TextView.

Here is my code:

```
public class CartRes {
    private String CartcategoryName;
    private String CartproductName;
    private String product_id;
    private int CartPrice;
    private int CartCount;

    public int getCartPrice() {
        Log.e("Product Check BeanGet", String.valueOf(CartPrice));
        return CartPrice;
    }

    public void setCartPrice(int cartPrice) {
        CartPrice = cartPrice;
        Log.e("Product Check Bean", String.valueOf(CartPrice));
    }

    public int getCartCount() {
        return CartCount;
    }

    public void setCartCount(int cartCount) {
        CartCount = cartCount;
    }
}
```

**Getter code snippet:**

```
 viewHolder.cartProduct.setText(cartRes.getCartproductName());
            viewHolder.cartQuantity.setText(cartRes.getCartcategoryName());
            viewHolder.cartCount.setText(cartRes.getCartCount());  //Not getting any value
            viewHolder.cartPrice.setText(cartRes.getCartPrice()); //Not getting any value
```

**Setter Code Snippet:**

```
cartRes = new CartRes();
                cartRes.setProduct_id(cartcursor.getString(cartcursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.CART_PDT_ID)));
                cartRes.setCartproductName(cartcursor.getString(cartcursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.CART_PDT_NAME)));
                cartRes.setCartcategoryName(cartcursor.getString(cartcursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.CART_CAT_NAME)));
                cartRes.setCartCount(cartcursor.getInt(cartcursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.CART_QUANTITY)));
                cartRes.setCartPrice(Integer.parseInt(cartcursor.getString(cartcursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.CART_PRICE))));


                cartcursor.moveToNext();
                cartBasket.add(cartRes);
}
```

**ViewHoder:**

```
  public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView cartProduct,
                cartQuantity,
                cartCount,
                cartPrice,
                cartPriceDum;
    }
```

**LogCat Values:**

03-17 16:24:10.708 16567-16567/? E/Product Check: PI 16 PistaIce Cream 2 360

03-17 16:24:10.710 16567-16567/? E/Product Check: PI 13 ButterScotchIce Cream 1 200

03-17 16:24:10.710 16567-16567/? E/Product Check: PI 11 ChocoIce Cream 1 140

03-17 16:24:10.711 16567-16567/? E/Product Check: PI 12 StrawberryIce Cream 1 100

03-17 16:24:10.711 16567-16567/? E/Product Check: PI 10 Vennila Ice Cream 1 70

Comment: This is returning something? `viewHolder.cartQuantity.setText(cartRes.getCartcategoryName());` Can you post your ViewHolder please?

Comment: Ya I am getting Categoryname.

Comment: posted an answer, let me know if it works :)

Comment: E/Product Check: PI 16 Pista Ice Cream 2 360
E/Product Check: PI 13 ButterScotchIce Cream 1 200
E/Product Check: PI 11 Choco Ice Cream 1 140

Comment: Product Id,Product Name,CategoryName,Count,Price respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this by converting it to string.

```
 viewHolder.cartCount.setText(cartRes.getCartCount()+"");  
 viewHolder.cartPrice.setText(cartRes.getCartPrice()+"");
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set Integer for Textview convert interger to string and set it text view.

Answer (score 1):

Since the values are `int` and `setText()` expect a `String` you should do this :

```
viewHolder.cartCount.setText(String.valueOf(cartRes.getCartCount())); 
viewHolder.cartPrice.setText(String.valueOf(cartRes.getCartPrice()));
```

Or also you can try the "trick" to put a `""` after/before the `int`

```
viewHolder.cartCount.setText(""+cartRes.getCartCount()); 
viewHolder.cartPrice.setText(""+cartRes.getCartPrice());
```